# C# reformating string into readable value using regex or other method

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string which basically looks like this in my compiler:

```
\n $\n22\n95\n\n
```

I would like to  format it into a string which would look like following:

```
22.95
```

Is this doable in C#? Especially since there are only \n in the string and I'm not sure how to filter it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the following way:

1) Split the string by `'\n'` using the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method

2) Filter the method using [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) and [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

3) then combine the resulting collection to a string using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) with `"."` as separator

Please try this algorithm, then post your attempt, and I will give you the entire code. With linq it is only 1 line of code. Drop me a comment if you have difficulties on the road

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of [Mong Zhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038328/6560478):

```
private static string StringDouble(string input)
{
    var intSplitResult =
        input.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(str =>
                {
                    int value;
                    bool success = int.TryParse(str, out value);
                    return new { value, success };
                })
                .Where(pair => pair.success)
                .Select(pair => pair.value);

    if (intSplitResult.Count() != 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
                   $"Invalid Input: [{input}]. Do not contains the right number of number!"
                   , nameof(input));
    }

    return string.Join(".", intSplitResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   in two steps using first positive look behind and positive look ahead    
   then replacing non digit and non dot.

            var text = "\n $\n22\n95\n\"

            var pattern = @"((?<=\d+))(\n)((?=\d+))";

            var st = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, @"$1.$3")

            st = Regex.Replace(st, @"[^\d.]", "");
```